# why does it show 404 when I test? org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc

Update in 2020/6/12
I have solved this problem. The cause of the problem is that my jetty server did not start properly. I changed jdk from 14 to 1.7. All the lessons that can be learned are:

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

It can always receive all web requests.

Thank you for answering my question, I hope your life goes well.

I wrote a control method and a test method under the SpringMVC system.
I also configured a local tomcat，Is it necessary to configure the correct url in tomcat.
The url address in tomcat is：

```
http://localhost:8080/chapter17
```

```
    @Test
    public void testhandle41() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        form.add("userName", "tom");
        form.add("password", "123456");
        form.add("age", "45");
        restTemplate.postForLocation(
                "http://localhost:8080/chapter17/user/handle41.html", form);
    }
```

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/handle41")
    public String handle41(@RequestBody String body) {
        System.out.println(body);
        return "success";
    }
```

and the error is

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null

    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:357)
    at com.smart.web.UserControllerTest.testhandle41(UserControllerTest.java:37)
```

Doesn't look like a problem with address resolution.
I tried the following two configurations.

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

and

```
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

In both cases, I tested using or not using.html. No good.

Comment: is your test in the same application that your controller is?

Comment: Well ...I just run the test program

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/handle41", **method =RequestMethod.POST**) http method is missing in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've shown the right method?

```
at com.smart.web.UserControllerTest.testhandle42(UserControllerTest.java:37)
```

It says the error occurred in testhandle42 and you've shown testhandle41.

Comment: But this problem does occur when running testhandle41

Comment: Can you remove ".html" and see what happens?

Comment: I tried it, you can see my new editor if you are convenient. Simply put, I didn’t succeed

Comment: Have you tried making a POST request to /handle41 manually with a rest api to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

you are requesting for following path http://localhost:8080/chapter17/user/handle41**.html** in your code

```
restTemplate.postForLocation(
                "http://localhost:8080/chapter17/user/handle41.html", form);
```

but the controller exposed end point as (without suffix **.html**)

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/handle41")
```

**Solution:**
You need to either change end point as :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/handle41.html")
```

OR

request for

```
restTemplate.postForLocation(
                "http://localhost:8080/chapter17/user/handle41", form);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the questioner. I have solved this problem. The cause of the problem is that my jetty server did not start properly. I changed jdk from 14 to 1.7. All the lessons that can be learned are:

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

It can always receive all web requests.

Thank you for answering my question, I hope your life goes well.